# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::query()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Why am I getting the following error?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::query()

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***") or die($mysqli->connect_error);

function checklogin($username, $password)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $result->bind_param("s", $username);
    $result->query();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `$mysqli->prepare()` will return an instance of `MySQLi_STMT`, but the `MySQLi_STMT` class doesn't have a `query()` method. Perhaps you meant [`execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)?

Comment: Then what is this on the mysqli manual page? if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf("%s (%s,%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

Comment: That's calling query() on the MySQLi connection, not on a prepared statement.